# select all available combination by specific field in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "teams" with fields: id, team_name

```
  id, team_name
```

- 1, Real Madrid
- 2, FC Barcelona
- 3, juventus
- 4, Milan

i want to select in **one query** all available VS combinations ...

like that:

> Real Madrid - FC Barcelona
>
> Real Madrid - juventus
>
> Real Madrid - Milan
>
> FC Barcelona - juventus
>
> FC Barcelona - Milan
>
> juventus - Milan

the purpose is to find solution for dynamic with different amount of rows if will be more teams in the tables...

this is possible? how... ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to simulate GROUP BY WITH CUBE in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085236/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-group-by-with-cube-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `self join`.

```
select t1.team_name,t2.team_name
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.team_name>t2.team_name --or if the id's are unique use 
                                          /* on t1.id < t2.id */
```

Comment: to get the resultset specified in the question... `on t1.id < t2.id`   (just a difference in which team is listed in column1 vs column2)... if the order of the rows is important, add an ORDER BY clause e.g. `ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id`  +10

Comment: @spencer7593 .. you are right..i edited my answer to include it.